# Why do people say Jesus is the only sinless person to walk this earth?

Tags: genesis, adam

I have heard this a many of time from people. Even read it in some post on this site. Can some one give me some scripture reference for this?
From what I get from the scriptures:

> (KJV) Genesis 3:8-11
>   8 And they heard the voice of the Lord God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the Lord God amongst the trees of the garden.
>
> 9 And the Lord God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou?>
>
> 10 And he said, I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was afraid, because I was naked; and I hid myself.<
>
> 11 And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat?<

The were sinless up to the point that they disobeyed GOD and ate of the forbidden fruit. They walked on the same earth. (God has not made another earth yet; he cleaned this one by means of a flood.)  For they had dressed and kept the garden. **They walked sinless.**

Comment: Jesus: "Abraham saw my day and was glad". When did Abraham do this? Did he have to die first, or did he see Jesus' day while he was alive? What does it mean to see Jesus' day?

Answer (score 1):

You do have a point.

But Adam and Eve's sinlessness had an end. And that end was when they disobeyed God by eating of the forbidden fruit.

On the other hand, Jesus Christ - the second Adam - finished His entire 33-year life on earth without sin. 1 Peter 2:22 and 2 Corinthians 5:21 speak on this behalf.

To be sinless means to have not sinned from the time you become aware of good and evil to the time you die and leave this earth.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put this in context - the Bible says that all people since Adam's fall have sinned 1 Kings 8:46, 2 Chron 6:26, Rom 3:10-18, 22, 23, 1 John 1:10, Prov 20:9, etc.  The Bible actually lists three "groups" of people that are sinless:

1. Jesus.  We are told numerous times that Jesus was sinless, even from the time of birth.  Heb 4;15, 7:27, 9:14, 2 Cor 5:21, 1 Peter 1:19, Luke 1:35, etc.
2. Adam and Eve before their fall.  Gen 2:15-25.
3. Forgiven sinners who are finally saved.  Col 1:22, 1 John 2:1, Jude 1:24, 1 Thess 3:13, 1 Cor 1:8, Phil 1:10, Rev 14:5, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do people say Jesus is the only sinless person to walk this earth?

As pointed out we inherit sin, as humans from our forbears (human fathers) as we all are descendants of sinful Adam:-

> NWT Romans 5:12  "That is why, just as through one man sin entered into the world and death through sin, and so death spread to all men because they had all sinned—."

Jesus did not have a human Father; his father was God, the one who created him like he created "Adam", so as his Father is sin free, Jesus would also be sin free:-

> NWT John 20:17 "Jesus said to her: “Stop clinging to me, for I have not yet ascended to the Father. But go to my brothers and say to them, **‘I am ascending to my Father and your Father and to my God and your God.’”**

The first man Adam was sin free at first until he became "lawless" (1 John 3:4 "Everyone who practices sin is also practicing lawlessness, and sin is lawlessness.") toward God and thus sinned.    Jesus lived a human life on earth but did not disobey, he was totally obedient to his God and Father (John 29:17); thus remained sin free:-

> NWT Hebrews 4:14, 15  "Therefore, since we have a great high priest who has passed through the heavens, ***Jesus the Son of God***, let us hold on to our public declaration of him. 15 For we do not have a high priest who cannot sympathize with our weaknesses, but ***we have one who has been tested in all respects as we have, but without sin.***